# How to completely remove CoreData from xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm trying to remove CoreData completely from my app because I have accidentally deleted the model and despite trying to fix it, I keep getting:

> Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model

Since I'm not using CoreData for this project, I decided to try to remove it entirely, but I'm having trouble. Here is what I've done so far:

1. Removed Import statements for CoreData framework and deleted from project
2. Removed all CoreData code from the AppDelegate
3. Removed the Model from "Copy Bundle Resources" in Build Phases
4. Restarted computer, reinstalled xcode SDK 8.4
5. Gone through the project folders to double check if I deleted them instead of just removing the reference.

And yet I'm still getting the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can't run my app. The Build phase works fine, but at startup, I get this error:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x182b8822c 0x1947fc0e4 0x1828192a0 0x1001543a4 0x100151580 0x1004a0fd4 0x1004a0f94 0x1004abdb8 0x1004a42c4 0x1004ae5d4 0x1004b0248 0x19505921c 0x195058ee0)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I understand that it is detecting a nil Model, so how do I remove CoreData entirely from the project?

My AppDelegate File:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  Oingo
//
//  Created by Matthew Acalin on 4/24/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Oingo Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "PFTwitterUtils+NativeTwitter.h"
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

   [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];

    return self;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


//    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5];

    // Initialize Parse.
    [Parse enableLocalDatastore];
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"xxx"
                  clientKey:@"xxx"];
    [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
    [PFTwitterUtils initializeWithConsumerKey:@"xxx" consumerSecret:@"xxxx"];

    //Initialize Twitter
    [[Twitter sharedInstance] startWithConsumerKey:@"xxxxx" consumerSecret:@"xxxx"];
    [Fabric with:@[[Twitter sharedInstance]]];
    [Fabric with:@[TwitterKit, CrashlyticsKit]];


    // [Optional] Track statistics around application opens.
    //[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

    //Initialize Facebook
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}


//Method added for facebook integration
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
//    [self saveContext];
}

//#pragma mark - Core Data stack
//
//@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
//@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
//@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
//
//- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
//    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "Oingo.Oingo" in the application's documents directory.
//    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
//}
//
//- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
//    // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
//    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
//        return _managedObjectModel;
//    }
//    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Oingo" withExtension:@"momd"];
//    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
//    return _managedObjectModel;
//}
//
//- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
//    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it.
//    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
//        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
//    }
//    
//    // Create the coordinator and store
//    
//    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
//    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Oingo.sqlite"];
//    NSError *error = nil;
//    NSString *failureReason = @"There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.";
//    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
//        // Report any error we got.
//        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
//        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = @"Failed to initialize the application's saved data";
//        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason;
//        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error;
//        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];
//        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
//        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
//        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
//        abort();
//    }
//    
//    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
//}
//
//
//- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
//    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
//    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
//        return _managedObjectContext;
//    }
//    
//    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
//    if (!coordinator) {
//        return nil;
//    }
//    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
//    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
//    return _managedObjectContext;
//}
//
//#pragma mark - Core Data Saving support
//
//- (void)saveContext {
//    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
//    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
//        NSError *error = nil;
//        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
//            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
//            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
//            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
//            abort();
//        }
//    }
//}

@end
```

Screenshot of Preferences/Location settings: Derived data = relative
[image]

Screenshot of output:
[image]

Comment: Hi. 
1) Perform a text search for tag `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` in xcode.
2) Perform `iOS Simulator->Reset Content & settings` if you got a crash in simulator.

Comment: Thanks for the comment: on 1) I did a search, there are a few references from my AppDelegate, but they are all already commented out. Re 2) I'm not able to build or open the simulator b/c of the error and if I build on device it get's stuck on the launch screen and shows the same error.  I've deleted the app completely from the device and tried to reload.  Still no dice.

Comment: Had you removed xcdatamodeld file from project?

Comment: @Bongoloid It's mean that part of your code is not rebuilded. The Xcode cache is not cleared. Try to change a `DerivedData` for your project. Go to `Xcode->Preference->Locations` and set the `Derived Data` to `Relative`. Then perform `Clean` and `Build`.

Comment: yes, deleted xcdatamodeld, still not working.  @Mozilla: I changed the Derived Data setting with Clean and build, did not work.  I added a screenshot of my settings page above.  Here is also output that might be helpful, but I'm not sure what it is telling me.  I can see the persistent store in a line item under a thread that has to do with twitter (see #9 in link).  http://i.stack.imgur.com/HgkBI.png  I'm not sure how to interpret this though.  Mind taking a look?

Comment: @Mozilla, sorry here is the link to the output: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jKabX.png

Comment: @Boingoloid Try to disable a twitter initialization in code for debug purpose.

Comment: @Mozilla, yes! thank you, that got the app running which is awesome.  Although, now I'm lost on what to do.  I need to reinitialize twitter somehow without triggering a creation of a persistent store.  I'm going to work on this, but any idea on next steps?

Comment: @Mozilla, got it working.  thank you!  After //commenting out the Twitter initialization, and leaving only the Fabric initialization, I got an error saying could not find twitterkitResources.bundle  It was in a subfolder and xcode didn't see it.  I added twitterKitResources, uncommented the Twitter shared instance initialization and the app appears to be running fine.  Thank you so much for your help!!!  Just made my day!